# Leave-one-out cross validation

Tags: regression, spss, cross-validation

I am working about elaborate a simple linear regression
so I need to evaluate many models.
I am asking how I can use leave-one-out cross validation to validate a simple linear regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have $n$ training examples. Then to do leave-one-out cross validation, you would first pick a training example to leave out, then perform your linear regression algorithm (gradient descent or another) on the remaining $n-1$ examples. You would then pick a different training example to leave out, perform regression on the remaining $n-1$ examples, and iterate until you've left out all examples exactly once. At the end, you would compare all $n$ coefficient vectors that you generated from your $n$ regressions to see if the coefficient values are approximately the same.

Comment: thank you can you tell me the way or how to do that with SPSS

Comment: I believe that you can use the linear regression function in SPSS to do each regression; but I'm not sure how you would automate the procedure to leave out one example at each step.

Comment: you are right so i will use a fonction of SPSS or i will use a syntaxe, thank you